# Improve loading of web controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've a modal form where I display articles in a pannier.

In my pannier, I've a tab and for each row of my tab, I have 8 web controls (5 ImageButton, 1 LinkButton, 1 TextBox, 1 DropDownList) with an event handler.

For exemple, if I have 98 articles in my pannier, I'll have 98 rows and 784 (98*8) web controls. It took too times to load.

How could I improve the loading ?

Here is my code to build the tab :

```
foreach (LignePanier lp in liste)
            {
                TableRow tr = new TableRow();
                tr.CssClass = "lignePanier";
                tr.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);
                tr.Attributes["style"] = "background-color:" + couleur;

                TableCell celluleLogo = new TableCell();
                celluleLogo.CssClass = "celluleTabArticle";
                celluleLogo.Width = Unit.Percentage(5);
                celluleLogo.Attributes["style"] = "text-align:center;";

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lp._ARTICLE._FOURNISSEUR._LOGO))
                {
                    System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton logoF = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton();
                    logoF.ImageUrl = ToolsImage.obtenirUrl(Request.Url.ToString()) + lp._ARTICLE._FOURNISSEUR._LOGO;
                    logoF.ID = "logoF" + i;
                    logoF.Width = Unit.Pixel(50);
                    logoF.Height = Unit.Pixel(50);
                    logoF.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(logoF_Click);

                    celluleLogo.Controls.Add(logoF);
                }

                TableCell tcITMREF = new TableCell();
                tcITMREF.CssClass = "cellulePanier";
                tcITMREF.Width = Unit.Percentage(7);
                tcITMREF.Text = lp._ARTICLE._ITMREF;

                TableCell tcFAM = new TableCell();

                if (j == 0)
                {
                    tcFAM.CssClass = "cellulePanier";
                    tcFAM.Width = Unit.Percentage(6);
                    tcFAM.RowSpan = item.Count();

                    tcFAM.Text = lp._ARTICLE._FAM1._FAM1 + "-" + lp._ARTICLE._FAM2._FAM2 + "-" + lp._ARTICLE._FAM3._FAM3 +
                        "-" + lp._ARTICLE._FAM4._FAM4;

                    String chaineFamille = "Famille 1 : " + lp._ARTICLE._FAM1._FAM1 + " (" + lp._ARTICLE._FAM1._FAMDES + ") \n";
                    chaineFamille += "Famille 2 : " + lp._ARTICLE._FAM2._FAM2 + " (" + lp._ARTICLE._FAM2._FAMDES + ") \n";
                    chaineFamille += "Famille 3 : " + lp._ARTICLE._FAM3._FAM3 + " (" + lp._ARTICLE._FAM3._FAMDES + ") \n";
                    chaineFamille += "Famille 4 : " + lp._ARTICLE._FAM4._FAM4 + " (" + lp._ARTICLE._FAM4._FAMDES + ")";

                    tcFAM.ToolTip = chaineFamille;
                }

                TableCell tcLIBLONFOUR = new TableCell();
                tcLIBLONFOUR.CssClass = "cellulePanier";
                tcLIBLONFOUR.Width = Unit.Percentage(21);

                Label lb = new Label();
                lb.Text = lp._ARTICLE._LIBLONFOUR.Split('[')[0];
                lb.Attributes["style"] = "text-decoration:underline;";

                Label label = new Label();
                label.Text = "<br/>" + lp._ARTICLE.obtenirChaineVenduParPourCommandeType();

                LinkButton lbLIBLONFOUR = new LinkButton();
                lbLIBLONFOUR.ID = "lbLIBLONFOUR" + i;
                lbLIBLONFOUR.Controls.Add(lb);
                lbLIBLONFOUR.Controls.Add(label);
                lbLIBLONFOUR.Click += new EventHandler(liblonfour_Click);

                tcLIBLONFOUR.Controls.Add(lbLIBLONFOUR);

                TableCell tcDelai = new TableCell();
                tcDelai.CssClass = "cellulePanier";
                tcDelai.Width = Unit.Percentage(4);
                tcDelai.Text = lp._ARTICLE._LTI + " j";
                tcDelai.Attributes["Style"] = "text-align:center";

                TableCell tcPANQTVVAL = new TableCell();
                tcPANQTVVAL.CssClass = "cellulePanier";
                tcPANQTVVAL.Width = Unit.Percentage(8);
                tcPANQTVVAL.Attributes["Style"] = "text-align:left";

                TextBox txtPANQTVVAL = new TextBox();
                txtPANQTVVAL.ID = "txt" + i;
                txtPANQTVVAL.AutoPostBack = true;
                txtPANQTVVAL.Width = Unit.Pixel(30);
                txtPANQTVVAL.CssClass = "txtLignePanier";
                txtPANQTVVAL.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtQTE_TextChanged);

                if (lp._PANQTVVAL == 0)
                {
                    txtPANQTVVAL.Attributes["style"] = "color:Red;";
                }

                if (lp._CREDAT == maxCREDAT)
                {
                    txtPANQTVVAL.Attributes["style"] += "background-color:#8BEAB7";
                }

                Label labelLIBCOND = new Label();
                labelLIBCOND.Text = lp._ARTICLE._LIBVTE;

                ImageButton buttonMoins = new ImageButton();
                buttonMoins.CssClass = "buttonMoins";
                buttonMoins.ID = "buttonMoins" + i;
                buttonMoins.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(buttonMoins_Click);
                buttonMoins.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/eWare_Theme/images/moins.png";

                ImageButton buttonPlus = new ImageButton();
                buttonPlus.CssClass = "buttonPlus";
                buttonPlus.ID = "buttonPlus" + i;
                buttonPlus.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(buttonPlus_Click);
                buttonPlus.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/eWare_Theme/images/plus.png";

                if (lp._PANQTVVAL == 0)
                {
                    txtPANQTVVAL.Text = "0";
                    this.buttonSubmit.Enabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    txtPANQTVVAL.Text = ToolsString.obtenirNombreArrondi(lp._PANQTVVAL, 2);
                }

                tcPANQTVVAL.Controls.Add(txtPANQTVVAL);
                tcPANQTVVAL.Controls.Add(labelLIBCOND);

                TableCell tcButton = new TableCell();
                tcButton.CssClass = "cellulePanier";
                tcButton.Attributes["style"] = "text-align:left;";
                tcButton.Width = Unit.Percentage(2);

                tcButton.Controls.Add(buttonPlus);
                tcButton.Controls.Add(buttonMoins);

                TableCell tcPANPRIUF = new TableCell();
                tcPANPRIUF.CssClass = "cellulePanier";
                tcPANPRIUF.Width = Unit.Percentage(7);
                tcPANPRIUF.Text = ToolsString.obtenirNombreArrondi(lp._ARTICLE._PRI * lp._ARTICLE._COEFCOND, 4) + " €";
                tcPANPRIUF.Attributes["Style"] = "text-align:left";

                TableCell tcTotal = new TableCell();
                tcTotal.CssClass = "cellulePanier";
                tcTotal.Width = Unit.Percentage(7);
                tcTotal.Attributes["Style"] = "text-align:left";

                decimal total = lp._PANQTVVAL * lp._ARTICLE._PRI * lp._ARTICLE._COEFCOND;

                tcTotal.Text = ToolsString.obtenirNombreArrondi(total, 2) + " €";

                TableCell tcPoubelle = new TableCell();
                tcPoubelle.Width = Unit.Percentage(27);
                tcPoubelle.ToolTip = "A l'entrepôt le " + lp._RCPDAT.ToString("D", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

                DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
                ddl.ID = "ddl" + i;
                ddl.AutoPostBack = true;
                ddl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(listeLivraisonPanier_SelectedIndexChanged);

                if (lp._ARTICLE._PRODINDISPO == 0)
                {
                    List<String> _liste = MgtDateLivraison.obtenirInstance().obtenirJourLivraison(lp._ARTICLE._FOURNISSEUR._FOURNISSEUR, heureLimite, lp._ARTICLE._LTI);

                    if (lp._DLVRCPDAT < DateTime.Parse(_liste[0].Split('*')[0]))
                    {
                        String s = lp._DLVRCPDAT.ToString("D",
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"));

                        ddl.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(s, s));
                    }

                    foreach (String s in _liste)
                    {
                        ddl.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(s, s));
                    }

                    //Si ma date est inférieur au premier élément de ma liste, c'est que je suis hors borne
                    if (lp._DLVRCPDAT < DateTime.Parse(_liste[0].Split('*')[0]))
                    {
                        ddl.CssClass = "dateHorsBorne";
                        //this.buttonSubmit.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }

                if (ddl.Items.FindByValue(lp._DLVRCPDAT.ToString("D",
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"))) != null)
                {
                    ddl.SelectedValue = lp._DLVRCPDAT.ToString("D",
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"));
                }
                else
                {
                    ddl.SelectedValue = lp._DLVRCPDAT.ToString("D",
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR")) + "*";
                }

                ImageButton buttonDuplicateRow = new ImageButton();
                buttonDuplicateRow.ID = "buttonDuplicateRow" + i;
                buttonDuplicateRow.CssClass = "buttonPlus";
                buttonDuplicateRow.ToolTip = "Dupliquer la ligne";
                buttonDuplicateRow.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(buttonDuplicateRow_Click);
                buttonDuplicateRow.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/eWare_Theme/images/plus.png";

                ImageButton buttonSupprimer = new ImageButton();
                buttonSupprimer.ID = "buttonSupprimer" + i;
                buttonSupprimer.CssClass = "buttonSupprimer";
                buttonSupprimer.OnClientClick = "return supprimerArticlePanier();";
                buttonSupprimer.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(buttonSupprimer_Click);
                buttonSupprimer.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/eWare_Theme/images/logo_delete.png";

                tcPoubelle.Controls.Add(ddl);
                tcPoubelle.Controls.Add(buttonDuplicateRow);
                tcPoubelle.Controls.Add(buttonSupprimer);

                TableCell tcInfos = new TableCell();
                tcInfos.Text = lp._ARTICLE._FOURNISSEUR._FOURNISSEUR + "." + lp._ARTICLE._ITMREF + "." +
                    lp._DLVRCPDAT.ToString().Split('*')[0] + "." + lp._RCPDAT.ToString() + "." + lp._ARTICLE._VENDUPAR +
                    "." + lp._ARTICLE._LIBCOND;

                tcInfos.Attributes["style"] = "display:none";

                //Si j == 0, je suis sur un nouveau regroupement, j'ajoute donc ma cellule à ma ligne.
                if (j == 0)
                {
                    tr.Cells.Add(tcFAM);

                    j = 1;
                }

                tr.Cells.Add(celluleLogo);

                tr.Cells.Add(tcITMREF);
                tr.Cells.Add(tcLIBLONFOUR);
                tr.Cells.Add(tcPANQTVVAL);
                tr.Cells.Add(tcButton);
                tr.Cells.Add(tcPANPRIUF);
                tr.Cells.Add(tcTotal);
                tr.Cells.Add(tcDelai);
                tr.Cells.Add(tcPoubelle);
                tr.Cells.Add(tcInfos);

                tabPanier.Rows.Add(tr);

                i++;
            }
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I'm not sure - with "pannier" is that a panel? If so - then check which tab is active and only load the controls on that tab. Also check out "UpdatePanels" - they might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of programmatically building all of the table cells and adding them to the controls collection, why not use a repeater control?  They are fairly lightweight, and 100 rows in a repeater shouldn't be an issue from a performance standpoint.

```
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptMyData">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Field1</th>
                            <th>Field2</th>
                            <th>Field3</th>
                            <th>Field4</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# ((MyObject)Container.DataItem).Image1Url %>" /></td>
                    <td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# ((MyObject)Container.DataItem).Image2Url %>" /></td>
                    <td><asp:ImageButton runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# ((MyObject)Container.DataItem).Image3Url %>" /></td>
                    <td><%# ((MyObject)Container.DataItem).SomeTextProperty %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

Then in your codebehind:

```
List<MyObject> myObjects = SomeClass.GetData();
rptMyData.DataSource = myObjects;
rptMyData.DataBind();
```

There is a ton of documentation on repeaters.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this solution :)

Comment: Can i have more than one headerTemplate in my repeater ?

Comment: You can only define one header template for the repeater.  If the header changes for each item, just skip the header and footer templates and put everything in the item template.

Comment: Thank you, it's better, but it's still long for 100 rows.